# Get answers from broadcast

Tags: c++11, udp, poco, datagram

I'm implementing a WSDiscovery service using `Poco::Net::DatagramSocket`.
This is the code:

```
string OnvifCamera::_sendFullProbe_for_Discovery() const noexcept
{
    Poco::Net::DatagramSocket ss(Poco::Net::IPAddress::IPv4);
    Poco::Net::SocketAddress sa(global.getDiscoveryIP(), global.getDiscoveryPort()); //IP "239.255.255.250", port 3702
    try
    {
        auto msg = _createXML_for_FullProbe();//is the XML probe x discovery
        ss.sendTo(msg.data(), msg.size(), sa);
    }
    catch (const Poco::IOException& ex)
    {
        cerr<<"\nException: "<<ex.what()<<", "<<ex.displayText()<<endl;
        return string();
    }
    ss.setBroadcast(true);

    char buffer[4096];
    int n = ss.receiveBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    cout<<"Got "<<n<<" bytes"<<endl;
    ss.close();
    return string(buffer);
}
```

Every device (IP Onvif camera), will answer with his XML data.

The problem is that if I have more cameras, I can get only 1 camera's answer. How can I get ALL the answers?

Comment: You need a _loop_ to receive each answer in turn, probably with a _timeout_ after which you give up listening for any new answers to arrive.

Comment: And you are right! thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only calling `receiveBytes` once, so that's why you only get one answer.

To receive the multiple individual answers you'll need to call `receiveBytes` repeatedly, and most likely implement a timeout after which you give up waiting for any more responses to be received (since you can't know apriori how many there'll be).

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of @Alnitack, this is the code (it works):

```
vector<XMLString> OnvifDiscovery::_sendFullProbe_for_Discovery() noexcept
{
    vector<XMLString> cameras_XML;
    DatagramSocket ss(IPAddress::IPv4);
    SocketAddress sa(_global.getDiscoveryIP(), _global.getDiscoveryPort());
    try
    {
        auto msg = _createXML_for_FullProbe();
        ss.sendTo(msg.data(), msg.size(), sa);
    }
    catch (const IOException& ex)
    {
        cerr<<"\nException: "<<ex.what()<<", "<<ex.displayText()<<endl;
        return cameras_XML;
    }

    ss.setBroadcast(true);

    Poco::Timespan timespan(2500000);
    ss.setReceiveTimeout (timespan);
    try {
        for(;;)
        {
            array<char, 4096> buffer {'\0'};
            int n = ss.receiveBytes(buffer.data(), sizeof(buffer));
            //cout<<"Received "<<n<<" bytes"<<endl;
            cameras_XML.push_back(buffer.data());
        }
    }
    catch(const Poco::TimeoutException &ex)
    {
        cout<<"Timeout:"<<ex.what()<<endl;
    }
    cout<<cameras_XML.size()<<endl;
    ss.close();
    return cameras_XML;
}
```